# Desired menu picker text color not being shown properly

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, picker, ios15

I have two views: CreateExerciseView and RepsViewStyle. Although CreateExerciseView has other view elements, I will condense the code to demonstrate my specific issue. It seems that the picker is not displaying with the desired colour I want, instead not appearing at all or in some cases, appearing as default blue text.

[image: The CreateExerciseView which incorrectly displays the picker colour]

Here is the condensed CreateExerciseView code:

```swift
struct CreateExerciseView: View {
  // Reps/Sets Properties
  @State var reps: String = "1 rep"
  @State var sets: String = "1 set"
  var body: some View {
    Group {
        // MARK: REPS AND SETS
        RepsViewStyle(reps: $reps, sets: $sets)
    }          
    .padding(.horizontal)              
  }
}
```

And here is the RepsViewStyle code:

```swift
struct RepsViewStyle: View {
    @Binding var reps: String
    @Binding var sets: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Select repetitions and sets: ")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding([.top, .trailing])
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Divider()
            
            HStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Picker(selection: $reps,
                       label: Text("\(reps)"),
                       content: {
                        ForEach(1..<100) { number in
                            if number == 1 {
                                Text("\(number) rep")
                                    .tag("\(number) rep")
                            } else {
                                Text("\(number) reps")
                                    .tag("\(number) reps")
                            }
                        }
                        
                       })
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    .padding(12)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .background(Color.MyTheme.redColor)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: Color.MyTheme.greyColor.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                
                
                Picker(selection: $sets,
                       label: Text("\(sets)"),
                       content: {
                        ForEach(1..<20) { number in
                            if number == 1 {
                                Text("\(number) set")
                                    .tag("\(number) set")
                            } else {
                                Text("\(number) sets")
                                    .tag("\(number) sets")
                            }
                        }
                        
                       })
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    .padding(12)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .background(Color.MyTheme.redColor)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: Color.MyTheme.greyColor.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried applying attributes to both the calling of the RepsViewStyle from the initial view as well as the pickers themselves but they do not seem to change at all.

Comment: As I see only global AccentColor (changed to white in Assets) works in this case. IMO this is a bug, because .tint must work (note .accentColor is deprecated now), but it does not. File feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.accentColor(.white)` to the Pickers, replacing `.foregroundColor(Color.white)` to set the "label" color white,
rather than the default blue color, if that is what you wanted to acheive.

Comment: The accentColor has been deprecated.. and does not work here, just in case.

Comment: ha yes, I can see from the docs that it has been deprecated, although it still works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it is difficult to style `Picker` in pure SwiftUI, as custom PickerStyles are not (yet) public.

A workaround for your case might be using `Menu` instead. The styling on this one works.

```
                Menu {
                    ForEach(1..<100) { number in
                        Button { reps = "\(number) reps" } label: {
                            if number == 1 {
                                Text("\(number) rep")
                            } else {
                                Text("\(number) reps")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("\(reps)")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding(12)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                }
```